# Create a banner that auto updates every 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, banner

Recently the channel https://www.youtube.com/c/trahan/ created a YouTube banner that auto updates every 5 minutes with a new one displaying how much he has donated to charity. I want to create a similar banner but with time until next upload. Is this possible, I'm guessing with some kind of script?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A channel banner is an image with no logic of its own. You cannot create a banner that updates conditionally.

You can use the YouTube API to [set a channel banner](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelBanners), but this will require you to obtain an API key and to write a script/executable/etc that calls the API to update the channel banner with a new image when appropriate.